# I'm only receiving the first packet, why?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I searched for a working TCP library, found this one: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24758/tcp-async-socket-server-client-communication

I implemented the six refactored classes from @Jesse C. Slicer's answer, modified it to allow an arbitrary port number (Added an `int Port` parameter to the `StartListening()` method).

I'd opened a connection with telnet/PuTTY, yet I'm only receiving the first typed character/init information from PuTTY, and no more. The server does not stop, since I can open new connections and do receive each of those single messages.

I tried the following code (There's a bit problem with the Async part, it actually blocks the rest of the program, that's why I use `BackgroundWorker`):

```
private BackgroundWorker serverThread;
    private IAsyncSocketListener server;
    public Connection()
    {
        server = AsyncSocketListener.Instance;
        serverThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        serverThread.DoWork += ServerThread_DoWork;
        serverThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void Server_OnReceived1(int id, string msg)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"String: {msg}");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Bytes: {string.Join(", ",msg.Select(x=>(int)x))}");
    }

    private void ServerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        server.MessageReceived += Server_OnReceived1;
        server.StartListening(1093);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callback (Server_OnReceived1), if you are waiting more data you should call again BeginReceive. If you don't do that your callback will not be called (beacause you have not notified that you are ready for more data) although there is data for it.

In the code of the link you provide, something like:

```
state.listener.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

Comment: I can't really get the grasp of this, should I put this line under these three lines, in the AsyncSocketListener class?
`if (messageReceived != null) { messageReceived(state.Id, state.Text);` 
If I use this, after a client disconnects, the CPU usage spins up to the maximum.  
I seem to be halfway through the problem now since I receive more than one message.

Comment: You have to check in the callback if the received lenght is 0. In this case you should not call again the BeginReceive, beacause the socket is closed by the other side of the communication.